# Getting alert "The agent process for node in cell is not running and the node is not in maintenance mode." in Component Stability tab

Tags: cluster, ibm, websphere

I'm trying to setup a clustered WebSphere Traditional 9 with a IBM HTTP Server as load balancer.

The nodes and clustered are created successfully, with the node agent started without issue.

However when i access the Component Stability screen, the below alert occured:

> Node : The agent process for node  in cell  is not running and the node is not in maintenance mode. Please
>   start the agent or place the node into maintenance mode.

The alert seems like more of a warning but i cannot find any info on it. Will it impact the servers functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out agent was killed by another process. Restarted the agent / node and everything returns normal.